# Missing complete data with $this->Auth->user()

Tags: cakephp-2.3

For some reason, when I get the result of $this->Auth->user() after successfully logging in, the result I get is :

```
array('password'=>'****', 'username'=>'theUsername')
```

This does show the correct information for the currently logged in user, but if I ask for something simple, like $this->Auth->user('id'), I get null.

In the past, I've been able to get all the fields for the currently logged in user. I don't really have anything special in the configuration, and I'm calling this from the Users->index() method, so I have full access to the Users model. If I try $this->User->find('first'), I get all the fields (for the first user of course).

I'm running PHP 5.5 and CakePHP 2.3.

UPDATE: here's my login method (I put in the debug info to check on the result). I get the same result as above. Do I need to do anything special to make sure $this->Auth->user() has all the fields from the users table?

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login($this->request->data)) {
            debug($this->Auth->user());
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to specify form data for Authentication.also try setting all auth user data into another variable. try this

```
public function login() {
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login() {
        debug($this->Auth->user());
    }
}
```

}

and try to assign into variable

```
 $this->set('current_user',$this->Auth->user);
```

if you want to use it in all controller,assign that in AppController

Comment: Sorry...I was trying a bunch of stuff at the time of the posting, including passing the request data directly, so that must have been the version I posted. At any rate, just after I make it through the $this->Auth->login() part, the only values in $this->Auth->user() only includes the username and password.